# Find the exact equation that has $x^3y + \sin x = c$ as the general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know people here hate the "do my homework" kind of posts but all the problems I've solved this far had me find the general solution to an equation and I'm not really seeing how to do the reverse of it, I'm not sure of how to start this.

I'm not far into ODE, currently using Erwin Kreyszig textbook and just got to integrating factor.

Comment: Can you confirm that by "sen" you mean "$\sin$", or describe that term?

Comment: Any requirements on the type, order, form the ODE you're after? I'd just differentiate whatever solution you have, if there is none.

Comment: @abiessu I'm sorry, it's called "sen" where I live, forgot to change it to sin.

Comment: @Kaster No requirements. So just different in respect to both x and y? So...
(3x²y+cosx)dx + (x³)dy = 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $$u=x^3y+\sin x-c$$
$$\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}=3x^2y+\cos x$$
$$\frac{\partial u }{\partial y}=x^3$$
$$(3x^2y+\cos x)dx+x^3dy=0$$